# Amazon SES - Count Email sent out Statistics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, aws-sdk

I used SES to sending emails, I have more than 10 verified domains under Amazon SES service but my problem is, I dont have any Statistics for each email address or domain. AWS console combine all send,bounce, ... together.

So How can I find out how many emails sendout from one of my domains ?

I dont want to do this on my own database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SNS you can track how many mails are sent from a particular email address or domain and how many bounce back. You need to configure your SES with SNS and have an active endpoint for configured SNS, you can then do whatever you want to do with the data, of course you don't need to save it to DB you can save it in  a flat file or anywhere you want.

Comment: I think SNS is only the solution since I should use SNS and call a Hook when email delivery o bounce or ... to count them.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon shows statistics in Web Interface of bounce, spam, rejected... based on SES regions. No matter if one sender or multiple senders use that particular region, SES will combine them all.
You can check bounces, ooto... for a particular sender by creating an SNS notification.
Like it or not, you'll eventually need to store that data in a db or any other safe place. Then you can play with d3 :-)

Comment: @alexandresaiz- For some reason the AWS stats aren't updating. After sending emails, the count doesn't increase in real-time. Any thoughts?

Comment: @SR please create a new question and direct me there, I'll be able to help there. This question has nothing to do with real time

Comment: Sure! Here it is the link- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39716465/delayed-ses-stats-updation