# Delayed SES Stats Updation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am noticing AWS SES stats are not being updated in real-time. After sending email, it takes time for sent count to increase on SES Dashboard. Sometimes it takes few minutes and sometimes it takes long.

Has anyone also experienced this? Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like the data that's available is divided into [windows of 15 minutes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetSendStatistics.html), so perhaps that's all the granularity that's provided. Is that more consistent with what you see? (The console typically uses the documented APIs for everything it shows you.)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 'Windows of 15 minutes' answers my question. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that the console is simply making a call to a standard API action (rather than using some kind a console-only backend service that is not documented or user-accessible -- such things are not unheard-of, but are pretty rare in AWS, so it's a reasonably safe assumption), it looks like this is not really designed to be real-time.  The stats are reported in 15 minute windows.

From the SES API reference:

> **GetSendStatistics**
>
> Returns the user's sending statistics. The result is a list of data points, representing the last two weeks of sending activity.
>
> Each data point in the list contains statistics for a 15-minute interval.
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_GetSendStatistics.html

Comment: That helps! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

AWS/SES dashboard stats are for pure hint performace but not to rely on them. In such case, if you want to have real time notifications of sent emails you will need to create SNS notifications. Keep in mind that Spam-Complaint notifications can take up to a couple of days as this is based on information provided by the ISP to Amazon. And complaints within the Gmail evil-system will NEVER get to you.

Comment: How can I get the count through SNS? I guess it only notifies about delivery, bounce & complaints, right?